# Load a method of User Control that is calling in another page (Windows Phone7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, user-controls

I have a UserControl with name UcMdisaese inside MainPage that execute an animation.

```
public partial class MDisaese : UserControl
{

        Public void Fases(int i)
          {
              _mdmodel.enojo();
              enojado = 0;
              _timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
          }

 }
```

Also I have a Page with name "Agrega_m" inside when ocurrs the event guardar_agrega_Click activate the animation I suppose, but doesn't work the method Fases to call the animation when I return to Mainpage that contain the User Control.
The question, How can load the method?

```
      public partial class Agrega_m: PhoneApplicationPage
         {

               private void guardar_agrega_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                   {
                       MDisaese hi = new MDisaese();
                       hi.fases(30);
                   }
          }
```

Comment: When the button in Agrega_m page is clicked, you want to perform an animation in UserControl which is in MainPage right?

Comment: Quit so! when load the main page destroy the calling to method